# How to deal with modules spread out across directories?

Tags: python, import, module

I've got a project in which I have a directory for each aspect of my project, and I'm running into issues of importing. Namely, importing things is becoming a nasty combination of `sys.path.append()`s and `PYTHONPATH` hackery.

How do projects that are spread out across multiple directories typically deal with this kind of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have directories for each module and you can put them under one module, then simplest solution is to use packages e.g.

```
myproject
    __init__.py
    mymodule1
        __init__.py
    mymodule2
        __init__.py
```

so you can import like

```
from myproject import mymodule1 etc
```

if you can't keep all directories under one tree, than treat them as separate projects/libs, in that case you should install them to correct python path using distutils etc read [this](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

I would set up a [virtual environment](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for my project and then install all of my modules into that environment where they would be found by the normal Python `import` process.

This does require that you update your virtual environment as you make changes to modules, but assuming a properly configure `setup.py` this is often as easy as:

```
$ cd /path/to/myproject
$ easy_install .
```

Also, you shouldn't need to muck about with *both* `PYTHONPATH` and `sys.path`.  Assuming a finite number of modules you could just make a shell script that set up `PYTHONPATH` appropriately and then source it in as necessary.

Comment: I wish I could upvote more than once as there are several good solution suggestions here that fit a wide range of projects that hit the multiple directory stage.